# How to get the id_token from Socialite and Google API Client in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using socialite to get the user access_token and use that token to get connect to the Google API Client in laravel. Everything is working fine. But I need to get the access token. But it is failed to get in the response. Let me know how to get the id_token from Google API client.

Here is my code

```
public function callback()
    {
        $user = \Socialite::driver('google')->user(); 
        $idToken = $this->getIdToken($user);
        var_dump($idToken);
    }

public function getIdToken($user){
    $google_client_token = [
        'access_token' => $user->token,
        'refresh_token' => $user->refreshToken,
        'expires_in' => $user->expiresIn
    ];

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessToken(json_encode($google_client_token));
    $oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); //exchange 'code' with access token, refresh token and id token
    $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $userData = $oauth->userinfo->get(); 

    return $userData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where coming from an Android device I didn't have access to the `access_token` so I had to pass an `auth_token` instead. On the server side here's how I handled it to retrieve an `access_token`.

```
  $driver = Socialite::driver('google');
  //In some cases coming from android an auth token may be required to get an access token 
  $access_token = $driver->getAccessTokenResponse($input['auth_token'])['access_token'];
  $googleUser = $driver->userFromToken($access_token);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, using the methods from Laravel's socialite documentation:

config/services add this to the array (with your own keys)

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_API_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_API_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('APP_URL').'/auth/adwords/callback'
],
```

Set up your routes as per the docs, and then add these to your class and it will dump out the token and expires_in

```
public function redirectToProvider() {
    return Socialite::with('google')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request) {
    $adwords_api_response = Socialite::with('google')->getAccessTokenResponse($request->code);

    dd($adwords_api_response);
}
```